# Does the Gitlab community edition allow to use the container registry?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Does the Gitlab CE (Community edition) allow to use the container registry? I didn't find this to be mentioned on the comparison site under https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/.

The documentation for the CE exists, so this should be possible?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/packages/container_registry/

Edit: There was a typo in the original post. The question is about Gitlab not Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it does. See documentation here for how to enable:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/packages/container_registry.html

Comment: If have found this page as well but I'm not sure if this applies to all editions...

Comment: Their documentation is usually pretty clear if you need a different edition.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. (Right now we have an old version that doesn't seem to have the option).

Comment: Yes, it does. I use it myself.